# Select items from list excluding multiple items based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

I want a list of items (td's in each tr) except for certain columns, say the 2nd and 3rd last column. How can it be done? I could decorate the specific td's to exclude with some attribute, or can I exclude them based on index alone.
Examples below remove the items I want, although I actually want to attach to mouse-over event but left out for simplicity.

Here is script get all columns except last 2 columns (example does not remove last 2):

```
$('table').find("tr td:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))").remove();
```

I tried this to exclude the 2nd and 3rd from the remove, but it doesn't like the comma separated selector (I thought you could do a multiple selector like this?):

```
$('table').find("tr td:not(:nth-last-child(2),:nth-last-child(3))").remove();
```

Here an example is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7U2m/).

edit: I'm using javascript 1.8.3

Comment: which jQuery Version you are using? It works fine on jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I'm using 1.8.3. Does seem to work fine in 1.9.1 but not in 1.8.3, if you look at the jsfiddle

Comment: that selectors were added in jQuery 1.9. That's why it works on  jQuery 1.9.1 but not on 1.8.3

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, you're using an old version of jQuery (1.7). [The :nth-last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/) was added in jQuery 1.9. Upgrade, and it will run correctly.

Comment: ahh yeah i gave you wrong link sorry but fine. I have opened more than  5 tabs of JSFiddle and copied wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').find("tr td").not(':nth-last-child(2), :nth-last-child(3)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following,

```
$('table').find("tr td::not(:eq(2)):not(:eq(1))");
```

I hope it will help you.